# Dns.GetHostEntry Method fails on IP Addresses

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I'm using a code intended to make a network connection, however when I try to use it via IP on my home router it fails on setting the `AddressList` array!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace GetSocket
{
    public class Program
    {
        private static Socket ConnectSocket(string server, int port)
        {
            Socket s = null;
            IPHostEntry hostEntry = null;

            // Get host related information.
            hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(server); // FAILS WITH IP ADDRESSES!

            // Loop through the AddressList to obtain the supported AddressFamily. This is to avoid
            // an exception that occurs when the host IP Address is not compatible with the address family
            // (typical in the IPv6 case).
            foreach (IPAddress address in hostEntry.AddressList)
            {
                IPEndPoint ipe = new IPEndPoint(address, port);
                Socket tempSocket =
                    new Socket(ipe.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

                tempSocket.Connect(ipe);

                if (tempSocket.Connected)
                {
                    s = tempSocket;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            return s;
        }

        // This method requests the home page content for the specified server.
        private static string SocketSendReceive(string server, int port)
        {
            string request = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: " + server +
                "\r\nConnection: Close\r\n\r\n";
            Byte[] bytesSent = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(request);
            Byte[] bytesReceived = new Byte[256];
            string page = "";

            // Create a socket connection with the specified server and port.
            using (Socket s = ConnectSocket(server, port))
            {

                if (s == null)
                    return ("Connection failed");

                // Send request to the server.
                s.Send(bytesSent, bytesSent.Length, 0);

                // Receive the server home page content.
                int bytes = 0;
                page = "Default HTML page on " + server + ":\r\n";

                // The following will block until the page is transmitted.
                do
                {
                    bytes = s.Receive(bytesReceived, bytesReceived.Length, 0);
                    page = page + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesReceived, 0, bytes);
                }
                while (bytes > 0);
            }

            return page;
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string host;
            int port = 80;

            if (args.Length == 0)
            {
                // If no server name is passed as argument to this program,
                // use the current host name as the default.
                host = Dns.GetHostName();
                host = "192.168.31.8";
            }
            else
                host = args[0];

            string result = SocketSendReceive(host, port);
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
}
```

So, why the line `hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(server);` doesn't set the `AddressList` array correctly instead of setting `{System.Net.IPAddress[0]}`?

Comment: What exception is it throwing? The docs say there are a few different exceptions it might through, which might help work out what's wrong: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.dns.gethostentry?view=net-5.0#System_Net_Dns_GetHostEntry_System_String_

Comment: Does the specified IP address really have a DNS entry? It fails if not.

Comment: It's a usb-tomato router, probably not. It throws no exception, it simple doesn't enter the foreach loop because the array is empty.

Comment: @Rui Monteiro, you can try the code **IPAddress[] ipv4Addresses = Array.FindAll(
    Dns.GetHostEntry(string.Empty).AddressList,
    a => a.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork);** to get the supported AddressFamily addresses. Based on my test, it works well for me.